# I make a video editing scripts but there is a bug here

Tags: python, opencv

```py
original_frames = [cv2.imread(os.path.join(original_frames_dir, filename)) for filename in sorted(os.listdir(original_frames_dir))]
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\start.py", line 61, in <module>
    target_frames = [cv2.imread(os.path.join(target_frames_dir, filename)) for filename in sorted(os.listdir(target_frames_dir))]
```

solving the problem, expected someone will answer me, I don't know what will be the result

Comment: The error is reported at line 61 of start.py, yet you posted just on line.  Code formatting fixed, irrelevant tags fixed.  Ask a _polite_ question rather than merely stating your expectations.

Comment: @Clifford To be fair, the last paragraph is probably boneheaded because the "wizard" the site displays to guide new users is equally boneheaded.